# How to access array inside the object with http Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http

I've got following structure of db.json

```
{
    "teams": [
        ...
    ],
    "matches": [
        { // matchday

            "id": "4b6023d0-8657-11ea-ab9d-57972c99f38c",
            "matches": [
                {
                    ...
                    "id": "4b604ae0-8657-11ea-ab9d-57972c99f38c"
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
        {...},
        {...},
    ]
}
```

How can I update match with ID?

I've tried this

```
const MATCHES_API = '/api/matches';

editMatch(match: Match, matchday: Matchday): Observable<Match> {
    return this.http
        .put(`${MATCHES_API}/${matchday.id}/matches/${match.id}`, match)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Also when I typed `/api/matches/${matchday.id}/matches/${match.id}` it returned me to the `/api/matches/` somehow.

How can I get to the match here?

*Update:* component's class, where I try to implement it

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PremierLeagueService } from '../../premier-league.service';
import { Matchday } from '../../models/matchday.interface';
import { Match } from '../../models/match.interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'league-matches',
    styleUrls: ['league-matches.component.scss'],
    template: `
        <div
            class="matchday"
            *ngFor="let matchday of matches; let i = index">

            <h2>Matchday {{ i + 1 }}</h2>

            <match-item
                *ngFor="let match of matchday.matches; let i = index; let c = count"
                [match]="match"
                [matchday]="matchday"
                [teamIndex]="i"
                [teamAmount]="c"
                (submitScore)="submitScore($event)"
                (getMatchday)="getMatchday($event)">
            </match-item>
        </div>
    `
})

export class LeagueMatchesComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(private premierLeagueService: PremierLeagueService) {}

    matches: Matchday[];
    currentMatchday: Matchday;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.premierLeagueService
            .getAllMatchdays()
            .subscribe((data: Matchday[]) => this.matches = data);
    }

    submitScore(match: Match) {
        this.premierLeagueService
            .editMatch(match)
            .subscribe((data: Match) => {
                this.matches.forEach((matchdayToCheck: Matchday) => {
                    matchdayToCheck.matches.forEach((matchToCheck: Match) => {
                        if (matchdayToCheck.id === match.id) {
                            matchToCheck = Object.assign({}, matchToCheck, match);
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
    }

     getMatchday(matchday: Matchday) {
         console.log(matchday);
         this.currentMatchday = matchday;
     }
}
```

This is what I get, when I try to edit match (add match score)

[image]

I have tried to access `matches array` in first `matchday`

```
http://localhost:4000/api/matches/4b6023d0-8657-11ea-ab9d-57972c99f38c

http://localhost:4000/api/matches/${matchday.id}
```

Accessed first matchday via ID

[image: Accessed first matchday via ID]
As you can see, `matchday` has `ID` and `matches array`

Trying to access match

```
http://localhost:4000/api/matches/4b6023d0-8657-11ea-ab9d-57972c99f38c/4b604ae0-8657-11ea-ab9d-57972c99f38c

http://localhost:4000/api/matches/${matchday.id}/${match.id}
```

which returns me this[image]

*Update 2.0:*

This is how my local db connected via webpack

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: cwd,
    compress: true,
    inline: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 4000,
    publicPath: '/build/',
    quiet: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    setup: function (app) {
      app.use('/api', jsonServer.router('db.json'));
    },
    stats: {
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }
  },
```

Comment: can you also share the component code where you are consuming this service you made?

Comment: The title is missleading

Comment: @PratyushSwain , added, could you, please, check it? I really have no idea, why I cannot access it. If you want, I can share GitHub link to my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using simple json server, something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server)

it should work by this url

```
`${MATCHES_API}/{match.id}`
```

```
const MATCHES_API = '/api/matches';

editMatch(match: Match, matchday: Matchday): Observable<Match> {
    return this.http
        .put(`${MATCHES_API}/{match.id}`, match)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, but it still doesn't work. I'm using db.json which was tied up via Webpack. I have added how it was connected in my question

Comment: @НовиковМаксим you said you can add github link, I can check, and I will try to help you

Comment: please, https://github.com/mxnvkv/Angular-Premier-League , I am trying to implement this feature in /app/premier-league/containers/league-matches/league-matches.component.ts. If you have any questions - feel free to write me

Comment: Hello, @НовиковМаксим I tested your project, I think the problem comes from JSON server package, What about to store the matchdays into another array by key `matchDays`, and every item into matchdays will have match Id, which match that belongs to.

and your Request URL will be `/api/matchDays?matchId=4b6023d0-8657-11ea-ab9d-57972c99f38c`

Comment: thank you! Currently, I'm updating whole match days, but I will try yours solution

Comment: Glad to help @НовиковМаксим